# How to auto-reconnect failed clients to another server in the server-cluster?

Tags: client-server, distributed-computing

We have a client/server distributed application where server is written in .Net and clients could be in c++, php, .net, java, python etc. All the clients in the environment are connected to atmost 1 server in the server-cluster. Servers are listening to clients on a socket.

So, when there are few clients connected to lets say server1, and server1 goes down, all new requests from those clients start failing. We are trying to find a solution that gives us this Live failover support that connected clients automatically start sending their requests to another server (server2) in the cluster.

One way of doing it is by adding an intelligence at client side but since we have our clients in various languages, we don't want to do it on client end. And its also impractical due to various other reasons.

The other way is by giving a virtual IP to all servers in the cluster and let all clients connect to this virtual IP instead of giving it different physical IP adderessses. But the problem with this approach is that once the clients are connected to a server, then there is no way of switching them over to the next server.

If it was for http traffic, then Network load balancer would have solved our problem. Even windows failover clustering does not seem to solve the issue.

Any ideas, any suggestions?